# Python: With Scrapy Script- Is this the best way to scrape urls from forums?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

What I want to do:

- Scrape all urls from this website: http://www.captainluffy.net/
  (my friends website, who I have permission to scrape urls from)
- However, I can't just brute everything, as I'll end up with lots of duplicate links (98% being duplicates)
- Even if I make my log file only contain unique urls, it still could be a couple of million links (which will take quite some time to get).

I can pause/resume my scrappy script thanks to this:
http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/jobs.html

I've set the script so it splits every 1,000,000 records. 
And the Python dictionary only checks url keys for duplicates within each text file. So at the very least, the urls within each file will be unique. If I had a bigger dictionary. it would tremendously slow down the process IMO. Having 1 duplicate (every 1,000,000 logs) is better than thousands.

This is the Python script code I'm currently using:

```html
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml import LxmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class MyItem(Item):
 url=Field()


f=open("items0"+".txt","w")
num=open("number.txt","w")
class someSpider(CrawlSpider):
  name = "My script"
  domain=raw_input("Enter the domain:\n")
  allowed_domains = [domain]
  starting_url=raw_input("Enter the starting url with protocol:\n")
  start_urls = [starting_url]
  i=0
  j=0
  dic={}
  global f

  rules = (Rule(LxmlLinkExtractor(allow_domains=(domain)), callback='parse_obj', follow=True),)


  def parse_obj(self,response):
    for link in LxmlLinkExtractor(allow_domains=(self.domain)).extract_links(response):
        item = MyItem()
        item['url'] = link.url
        if self.dic.has_key(item['url']):
          continue
        global f
        global num
        f.write(item['url']+"\n")
        self.dic[item['url']]=True
        self.i+=1
        if self.i%1000000==0:
          self.j+=1
          f.close()
          f=open("items"+str(self.j)+".txt","w")
          num.write(str(self.j+1)+"\n")
```

Does anybody have a better method to scrape? 
How many log files do you estimate my scrapy script will take from a website like this?

Answer (score 1):

Scrapy drop duplicate request by [DUPEFILTER_CLASS](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#dupefilter-class), the default setting is [RFPDupeFilter](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/1.0/scrapy/dupefilters.py#L28), which is similar like your method but not save seen urls to many files.

I have created a POC.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml import LxmlLinkExtractor


class ExampleSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "ExampleSpider"
    allowed_domains = ["www.example.com", "www.iana.org"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://www.example.com/',
    )
    rules = (Rule(LxmlLinkExtractor(allow_domains=allowed_domains), callback='parse_obj', follow=True),)
    log_file = open('test.log', 'a')

    def parse_obj(self, response):
        #self.logger.info(response.url)
        self.logger.info(self.settings['DUPEFILTER_CLASS'])
        self.log_file.write(response.url + '\n')
```

Run it with `scrapy crawl ExampleSpider -s DUPEFILTER_DEBUG=1`, there should be some debug info like following.

> [scrapy] DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET http://www.iana.org/about/framework>

Comment: I just ran your example, but I don't see where the output file is. This is what I ran: scrapy runspider POC.py -s DUPEFILTER_DEBUG=1 but I stopped it before it finished (ctrl +c) on your exact example (nothing changed).

Comment: It should be in the console stdout. What is `self.logger.info(self.settings["DUPEFILTER_CLASS"])` output in the spider?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/6YUJS0y.png - when I run the spider, but quickly closed to printscreen to show you. Where is the console stdout? Can you please change your code to make it so the output url files appear in the same directory where the script is run from?

Comment: I have updated answer, it will save crawled pages url to test.log, and print DUPEFILTER_CLASS value in console.

Comment: I just ran it and it didn't save any url links into the test log (txt document) - http://i.imgur.com/p94OiMe.png - Still at 0kb, so when I open it up, nothing is in it.

Comment: It seems the `parse_obj` function is not be called, maybe there is a typo.

Comment: I literally copied your code word for word.: http://i.imgur.com/tvfS069.png - & this is what I do to run the script: scrapy runspider POC.py -s DUPEFILTER_DEBUG=1 http://i.imgur.com/UujmrTW.png

Comment: So you must be missing something in your code or have a typo in it (which I can't spot).

Comment: Sorry, I have pasted code with wrong indent, that make `parse_obj` function  out of `ExampleSpider` class scope. It's fixed now, please try again.

Comment: Yes, it works now. I'll try and leave it on for a few hours, just to compare how fast it logs links in contrast to my script.